# Unable to create procedure with case expression in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Considering this table:

```
CREATE TABLE RACKRATE 
(
    RackRateID SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    RoomTypeID SMALLINT REFERENCES ROOMTYPE(RoomTypeID) NOT NULL,
    HotelID SMALLINT REFERENCES HOTEL(HotelID) NOT NULL,
    RackRate SMALLMONEY NOT NULL,
    RackRateBegin DATE NOT NULL,
    RackRateEnd DATE NOT NULL,
    RackRateDescription VARCHAR(200)
);
```

I'm trying to create a stored procedure to update the table, like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_UpdateRackRates
    @hotelid smallint,
    @roomtypeid smallint = NULL,
    @rackratedescription varchar(200) = NULL,
    @percent decimal(6,4)
AS
    UPDATE RACKRATE 
    SET RackRate = CASE 
                       WHEN @percent >= 0 
                           THEN CEILING(RackRate * ((100 + @percent)/100))
                       ELSE FLOOR(RackRate * ((100 + @percent)/100))
                   END
    WHERE 
        (CASE
             WHEN @roomtypeid IS NOT NULL AND @rackratedescription IS NOT NULL
                 THEN HotelID = @hotelid AND RackRateDescription = @rackratedescription
             WHEN @hotelid IS NOT NULL 
                 THEN HotelID = @hotelid
             WHEN @rackratedescription IS NOT NULL 
                 THEN RackRateDescription = @RACKRATEDESCRIPTION
         END);
```

When I run this in SQL Server, I get this error

> Incorrect syntax near '='

pointing at the first = sign in the where clause.

As a sanity check, I created the same table in sqlite and checked this same update statement with it, and sqlite worked just fine (obviously just the update statement, sqlite doesn't have stored procedures).

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: It works in other database doesn't means it will works in `SQL Server`. SQL Server does not support such syntax. Do refer to documentation : [WHERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [Search condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/search-condition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Each `WHEN... THEN...` branch of a case expression is meant to return a single value.

Comment: `CASE` is an **expression** in T-SQL which can return one atomic value - it **cannot** return expressions to be evaluated (`THEN HotelID = @hotelid`) ....

Comment: odd, looking at the documentation for sql server, it seems to imply that the then clause in a case statement can be any expression. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @AlwaysLearning in this case each then expression is returning a single value, which either evaluates to true or false... right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does not really have a boolean type. (Or more properly, SQL Server treats Boolean in a separate category from other types, with limited usages.) The BIT type is close, but not equivalent.

(See SQLpro's note below regarding ISO SQL standard compliance.)

The following is a direct adaptation of your logic that takes the results of each case condition and emits a 1 or 0. The WHERE clause then checks for an overall result = 1. I also added an `ELSE 1` to handle the "nothing to check" case.

```
    WHERE 1 =
        (CASE
             WHEN @roomtypeid IS NOT NULL AND @rackratedescription IS NOT NULL
                 THEN CASE WHEN HotelID = @hotelid AND RackRateDescription = @rackratedescription
                      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
             WHEN @hotelid IS NOT NULL 
                 THEN CASE WHEN HotelID = @hotelid
                      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
             WHEN @rackratedescription IS NOT NULL 
                 THEN CASE WHEN RackRateDescription = @RACKRATEDESCRIPTION
                      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
             ELSE 1
         END);
```

There may be ways to reduce this, but I believe the current form reflects your intent.

**Side note:** Be aware that the above approach may lead to performance issues. The SQL Server query optimizer will not be able to effectively use an index to identify rows to be updated, so a table scan is likely to occur with every execution (or at best a complex index scan).

A better approach that would allow index optimization would be to split the `UPDATE` into three separate statements, contained within an `IF-ELSE` structure, and with each having a simplified `WHERE` condition.

**Side note 2:** Did you indend to check for `@roomtypeid IS NOT NULL` and then apply a `HotelID = @hotelid` condition in the first case branch?

Comment: thanks, your note about sql server not having boolean types is what made it click for me. it's just weird, because outside of a case statement I don't have to use this return 1 business. It probably would be more concise if I used if else clauses (which sqlite doesn't support) but I wan't to keep it portable. If I'm understanding this query properly, I think I would prefer ELSE 0 at the end (do nothing when both are null instead of update every single row).

Comment: @T_N "SQL Server does not really have a boolean type." More precisely the BIT type is exactly the boolean type in SQL Server ISO language from the origin (SQL86) to the 1999 version that introduced BOOLEAN. Many SQL IOS functions returns BIT instead of a bolean (as an example all the GIS functions ST...).

Comment: @TheMungler - See side notes above.

Comment: regarding side note 2: actually I intended to check that hotelid matches in every case, and only vary whether or not I'm checking roomtypeid and rackratedescription based on whether or not the parameters were null.  Really a logic error on my part in the original question. Your answer addresses the syntax errors perfectly though, which is where I was running into trouble.

Answer (score -2):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_UpdateRackRates
@hotelid smallint,
@roomtypeid smallint = null,
@rackratedescription varchar(200) = null,
@percent decimal(6,4)
AS
UPDATE RACKRATE SET RackRate = 
CASE WHEN @percent >= 0 THEN CEILING(RackRate * ((100 + @percent)/100))
ELSE FLOOR(RackRate * ((100 + @percent)/100))
  END
WHERE (CASE
  WHEN @roomtypeid IS NOT NULL AND @rackratedescription IS NOT NULL
 THEN HotelID = @hotelid AND RackRateDescription = @rackratedescription
WHEN @hotelid IS NOT NULL THEN HotelID = @hotelid
WHEN @rackratedescription IS NOT NULL THEN RackRateDescription = @rackratedescription
```

END);

Comment: this seems to be exactly what I submitted, and still has the exact same problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).